# Is there something wrong with splitting a command line with split(' ')?

Tags: python, unix, split

In most [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) (I found) to the question *"How to run an external command"* I see something along the lines

> If you want to run `ls -l` you need to use `subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])`

What I normally do when I know what I will be running is to call `subprocess.call('ls -l'.split(' '))` to have visually the command line in one piece (it is usually a variable).

Is there anything inherently wrong with using `split()` as opposed to building the list manually (again, when the command is known). Or are these answers crafted to explicitly show that a list is needed?

I tried to find some drawbacks (multiple spaces, escaped spaces, ...) but I do not see where that approach could go wrong?

Note: this question is specifically about the robustness of splitting on spaces, not the security issues or other (very important) considerations as such.

Comment: You should be using [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) for this.

Comment: in most cases you don't have constant command arguments: `["ls", "-l", pathname]`

Comment: I agree with Ashwini.  `shlex.split` will handle quoting properly ... `ls -l "file with spaces"`, `str.split` won't.  Additionally, 99% of the time when you write `str.split(' ')`, you _really_ want `str.split()` (which will handle consecutive runs of whitespace in a way that you _usually_ want).

Comment: You may use commands.getoutput() instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that this works:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['ls', '-l', "my file"])
-rw-rw---- 1 john john 0 May  5 10:46 my file
0
```

But this does not:

```
>>> subprocess.call('ls -l "my file"'.split(' '))
ls: cannot access "my: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file": No such file or directory
2
```

And this does work:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('ls -l "my file"')
['ls', '-l', 'my file']
>>> subprocess.call(shlex.split('ls -l "my file"'))
-rw-rw---- 1 john john 0 May  5 10:46 my file
0
```

#### Recommendation

In python philosphy, [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  Thus, of those three forms, use this one:

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l', 'my file'])
```

This avoids all preprocessing and shows you clearly and unambiguously and *explicitly* what will be executed and what its arguments are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really certain that there are no issues with unescaped characters (including spaces in filenames), then I don't see any problem.

But you might find it easier to use `os.system("ls -l")` instead. Just note that if you want to use the result code, it should be right shifted by 8 bits:

```
exit_code = os.system("ls -l") >> 8
```

Alternatively (more robust, but also more work to type...):

```
subprocess.call('ls -l', shell=True)
```

Then you let the shell handle the splitting.

Edit: also mention subprocess.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for os.system recommend using subprocess instead.